# Perl Read/Write File Handle - Unable to Overwrite

Tags: perl

I have a Perl Script which performs a specific operation and based on the result, it should update a file.

Basic overview is:

1. Read a value from the file handle, FILE
2. Perform some operation and then compare the result with the value stored in INPUT file.
3. If there is a change, then update the file corresponding to File Handle.

When I say, update, I mean, overwrite the existing value in INPUT file with the new one.

An overview of the script:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use diagnostics;

$input=$ARGV[0];
open(FILE,"+<",$input) || die("Couldn't open the file, $input with error: $!\n");

# perform some operation and set $new_value here.

while(<FILE>)
{
chomp $_;
$old_value=$_;
if($new_value!=$old_value)
{
 print FILE $new_value,"\n";
}
}

close FILE;
```

However, this appends the $new_value to the file instead of overwriting it.

I have read the documentation in several places for this mode of FILE Handle and everywhere it says, read/write mode without append.

I am not sure, why it is unable to overwrite. One reason I could think of is, since I am reading from the  handle in the while loop and trying to overwrite it at the same time, it might not work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your guess is right. You first read the file so file pointer is actually in the position of end of old value. I didn't try this myself, but you can probably seek file pointer to 0 before print it out.

```
seek(FILE, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add `truncate` to your program along with `seek`.

```
if( $new_value != $old_value )
{
    seek( FILE, 0, 0 );
    truncate FILE, 0;
    print FILE $new_value,"\n";
}
```

Since the file is opened for reading and writing, writing a shorter `$new_value` will leave some of the `$old_value` in the file. `truncate` will remove it.

See `perldoc -f seek` and `perldoc -f truncate` for details.

Answer (score 0):

you have to close the file handle and open a different one (or the same one if you like) set to the output file. like this.

```
close FILE;
open FILE, ">$input" or die $!;

...

close FILE;
```

that should do the trick

Comment: Hello. Yes, I already used that workaround and it worked for me. However, I wanted to do it with the same file handle in order to reduce the number of lines of code.